# Can excessive printing cause a job step to fail?

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I'm doing debugging of a SQL Server job that keeps failing without obvious cause while also completing every calculation properly. The situation is as follows:

The job runs a procedure surrounded by try/catch (log then throw exception), has a log step before and after, and extensive logging inside that writes logs on practically every relevant step. It calls a number of smaller procedures that each handles some part of the logic, and one external procedure that's not under my control/responsibility to maintain.

The execution of the job completes, writing down every result and the logs behave as expected.

Except the job fails. Every time. And the excessive use of PRINT done by the external procedure keeps hiding the actual cause of the failure because it all goes into the job step's message, which is then completely useless.

My primary question is this: if a procedure uses extensive printing, inside a job step, will that eventually cause the job to fail when logging completion, even if every step inside completed successfully? And if so, is there any documentation that indicates what the limits/settings are for this that I can consult?

Comment: Unlikely, but, as you've found out, all those `PRINT` statements are written to the log and that has a character limit. Perhaps, instead of `PRINT`ing, you should be logging to a table.

Comment: @ThomA Alas, I did. I killed literally every excessive print statement except the ones that print error messages for easier capture.  Except I don't have access to the external procedure, nor can I in any way edit it. I'm trying to get information to understand the underlying issue so I can properly argue with the owner of said procedure to fix his printing.

Comment: If you're calling the procedure, then you could wrap the call in a `TRY...CATCH` and then, before you re`THROW` the error, write that error to a (log) table.

Comment: I did. There's no errors. Anywhere. I have every single procedure call surrounded in a try catch, and I log beginning and completion times for later statistics, along with error handling. For most errors, I get a nice stack trace in later logs with details of what the input parameters were.

Comment: If ther's no errors, have you set the agent task to *report failure* after a successful run? Agent tasks don't fail unless something *failed* or you explicitly told it to.

Comment: It's worth noting, as well, that an Agent Task can complete and still fail. For example, if you have agent task with a statement like `EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT 0/0;';` and then after that had a bunch of `INSERT` statements in the same batch, then agent task would report a failure (due to the divide by zero error), but as the error is in a deferred batch it wouldn't be an aborting error and so all the `INSERT` statements would still run. So even if you're seeing everything appear to be successful, *something* could still be reporting an error.

Comment: This was definitely it. I did not take into account the severity of an issue on a remote server, and the printing hid the actual error that occurred, while the SQL job refuses to ignore it, hence resulting in an unloggable error. It never triggered try/catch, because the severity was apparently too low for catch, not not low enough to not trip the job.

Comment: @ThomA - you don't need the `EXEC`. Divide by zero isn't a batch aborting error https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZAJb.png

Comment: It was just a random example, @MartinSmith .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thom A for his assistance in the comments, he got me looking in the right place.

The above issue is not the source of the problem, the but the underlying issue was hidden entirely by the printing.
Fortunately, if set properly, job steps keep extensive logging in files, which makes checking possible later on, and that's what allowed me to trace the issue to a pair of Msg rows that pointed at the underlying issue.

Clearly, the fact that a remote server error of a procedure does not immediately dump into Catch is an issue I'll have to figure out how to overcome, but at least i can actually find the issue now.